# angularjs submit within Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Bootstrap 3 Modal containing a list of items to choose from, the list is populated via Angular. When you click on an item in the list, I populate a hidden field to hold the chosen values using a bit of JS, see below. The hidden fields are tied to the $scope. When I submit the form, the items are not passed. I have seen a number of comments that suggest I need to refer to the parent scope, e.g. ng-model="$parent.Description", but this does not seem to work either. Any suggestions?

```
$scope.OpenFavsModal = function () {
                  var url = "/GetFavs/";
                  $http.get(url)
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $scope.myData = data;
                            $('#AddFavsModal').modal('show');

                        });
              };


    <form class="form-horizonatal" ng-submit="InsertFavourite()" id="frmAddFav">
    <div class="modal fade" id="AddFavsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >

                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Add</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">

                            <input type="text" id="hidDescription" class="form-control" ng-model="myData.Description"  />
                            <input type="text" id="hidSpectRefno" class="form-control" ng-model="myData.id" />

                         <ul style="height:300px; overflow-y:scroll; float:left;" id="ulS" >

                             <li ng-repeat="fav in myData" value="{{fav.id}}" >
                                    {{fav.Description}} 
                                </li>

                         </ul>

                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit"  class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>


                  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

              </div><!-- /.modal -->
            </form>


<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ulS").on("click", "li", function () {
            $("#hidDescription").val($(this).text());
            $("#hidId").val($(this).val());
        });
        });

 </script>
```

Comment: You code is, very hard to read. you show a bit of jquery and abit of your controller. I just want to ask "I populate a hidden field to hold the chosen values using a bit of JS", the JS means jquery? if you change textbox value outside of angular, angular does not know the changes, it will obviously never submit the data.

Comment: I managed to get this working by putting ng-click on the <LI> and passing the favourites object in the click event. Could have been the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by putting ng-click on the

and passing the favourites object in the click event. Could have been the scope.

```
<ul style="height:300px; overflow-y:scroll; float:left;" id="ul" >
<li ng-repeat="fav in favourites" value="{{fav.Refno}}"  ng-model="fav.Refno" ng-click="InsertFavourite(fav)">
{{fav.Description}} 
</li>
</ul>
```